# Spectrum theorem for p-adic matrix analysis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

Recently, I met a problem related to p-adic matrices in my research, the key of the problem can be summarized in the following way: 1: whether there exist spectrum theorem for p-adic matrix.\

2: whether invertible p-adic matrix is dense in
$C_{p}^{n\times n}$

3:whether diagonalizable p-adic matrix is dense in
$C_{p}^{n\times n}$, i.e. for almost every matrix $V \in C_{p}^{n \times n} $, there exist invertible $P$, $P^{-1}VP$ is a diagonalizable matrix.

Any reference and comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Crosspost http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123533/spectrum-theorem-for-p-adic-matrix-analysis